# how to edit fbx files with c# or open them with notepad

Tags: c#, fbx, blender-2.76

I need to edit content of fbx files  which created in Blender3d. I use C# to edit them. When i try to read a fbx file with c# or open it with a notepad, I encounter a lot of bad characters like below:

[image: FBX File Opening with Notepad]

I tried to use some third party libraries like Assimp.NET but none of them was helpful.

**Does anyone know a way to read fbx files with C# or open it without bad characters with Notepad?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a library which let's people to create, edit or convert Binary FBX and Ascii FBX Files. Github link is below:

https://github.com/hamish-milne/FbxWriter